# Refer to few id's in one command getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code as below:

```
function getRowMarkup(rowNo) {
  return '<tr class="row" data-row-no="'+rowNo+'"> \
    <td class="row-no">'+rowNo+'.</td> \
    <td><input type="text" name="ItemUnit_'+rowNo+'" class="item-unit" /></td> \
    <td><input type="text" name="ItemUnit_'+rowNo+'" class="item-unit" /></td> \
    <td><input type="text" name="ItemUnit_'+rowNo+'" class="item-unit" /></td> \
    <td><input type="number" name="ItemUnit_'+rowNo+'" class="item-unit" id="jeden'+rowNo+'"/></td> \
    <td><input type="number" name="ItemUnit_'+rowNo+'" class="item-unit" id="dwa'+rowNo+'"/></td> \
    <td><div  class="item-unit" id="trzy'+rowNo+'"/></div></td> \
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete-row">Delete</a></td> \
    </tr>';
}
```

This function works properly and add new positions into table. I'd like to have button which will calculate inputs whith id=""jeden'+rowNo+'"" and id="dwa'+rowNo+'" and show me score in div with id="trzy'+rowNo+'".
How can I fix my code below to get variable id's in getElementById. As you probably imagine, id's will change after adding new rows, they'll have nextnumber, so it'll be for example: jeden1, jeden2, jeden3 etc.
How can I put these variable id's into my code.

```
function numberMult() {
  var firstNumber = Number(document.getElementById("jeden"+"rowNo").value);
  var secondNumber =Number(document.getElementById("dwa"+"rowNo").value);
  var result = firstNumber * secondNumber
  document.getElementById("trzy"+"rowNo").innerHTML = result;
};
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: The `rowNo` variable should not be in quotes. When it's in quotes, it's just a string.

Comment: Without quotes also doesn't work.

Comment: `rowNo` shouldn't be in quotes, secondly you never pass the `rowNo` to your numberMult function.

Comment: So what I am supossed to do? How can I refer to these variables ids>

Answer (score 0):

1) you can't refer to few ids with getElementById. It returns single element selected by id. Perhaps you will be interested in [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

2) rowNo is a variable and your actual markup generated with value from this variable, so you, perhaps, will have ids like `id="jeden0"`, `id="jeden1"` etc...

3) In your function `numberMult` you need to pass variable `rowNo` just like in  `getRowMarkup`

4) Then use this variable to select elements. Something like:

```
function numberMult(rowNo) {
  // do not use quotes for variable
  var firstNumber = Number(document.getElementById("jeden"+rowNo).value);
  var secondNumber =Number(document.getElementById("dwa"+rowNo).value);
  var result = firstNumber * secondNumber
  document.getElementById("trzy"+rowNo).innerHTML = result;
};
```